# pandas combine a data frame with another groupby dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two data frames with structure as given below.

```
>>> df1
   IID   NAME   TEXT
0   10    One  AA,AB
1   11    Two  AB,AC
2   12  Three     AB
3   13   Four     AC
>>> df2
   IID TEXT
0   10   aa
1   10   ab
2   11  abc
3   11  a,c
4   11   ab
5   12   AA
6   13   AC
7   13   ad
8   13  abc
```

I want them to combine such that new data frame is a copy of df1 with the TEXT field appearing in df2 for the corresponding IID is appended to the TEXT field of df1 with duplicates removed (cases insensitive duplication check).

My expected output is

```
>>> df1
   IID   NAME           TEXT
0   10    One          AA,AB
1   11    Two  AB,AC,ABC,A,C
2   12  Three          AB,AA
3   13   Four      AC,AD,ABC
```

I tried with groupby on df2, but how can I do the joint of the groupie object to a dataframe ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) to create the skeleton with duplicates , then [`series.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) with `groupby+unique` for de-duplicating

```
out = (pd.concat((df1,df2),sort=False).groupby('IID')
      .agg({'NAME':'first','TEXT':','.join}).reset_index())
out['TEXT'] = (out['TEXT'].str.upper().str.split(',').explode()
              .groupby(level=0).unique().str.join(','))
print(out)
```

---

```
   IID   NAME           TEXT
0   10    One          AA,AB
1   11    Two  AB,AC,ABC,A,C
2   12  Three          AB,AA
3   13   Four      AC,AD,ABC
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the reverse steps. First combined the rows having the same values to a list then merge and then combine the two columns into a single column.

**df1:**

```
    IID NAME    TEXT
0   10  One     AA,AB
1   11  Two     AB,AC
2   12  Three   AB
3   13  Four    AC
```

**df2:**

```
    IID TEXT
0   10  aa
1   10  ab
2   11  abc
3   11  a,c
4   11  ab
5   12  AA
6   13  AC
7   13  ad
8   13  abc
```

---

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df2.groupby("IID")['TEXT'].apply(list).transform(lambda x: ','.join(x).upper()).reset_index())
```

**df3:**

```
IID TEXT
0   10  AA,AB
1   11  ABC,A,C,AB
2   12  AA
3   13  AC,AD,ABC
```

---

```
df4 = pd.merge(df1,df3,on='IID')
```

---

**df4:**

```
    IID NAME    TEXT_x  TEXT_y
0   10  One     AA,AB   AA,AB
1   11  Two     AB,AC   ABC,A,C,AB
2   12  Three   AB  AA
3   13  Four    AC  AC,AD,ABC
```

---

```
df4['TEXT'] = df4[['TEXT_x','TEXT_y']].apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(pd.unique(','.join(x).split(','))),
    axis=1
)
df4.drop(['TEXT_x','TEXT_y'],axis=1)
```

#### OR

```
df5 = df1.assign(TEXT = df4.apply(
    lambda x: ','.join(pd.unique(','.join(x[['TEXT_x','TEXT_y']]).split(','))),
    axis=1))
```

**df4/df5:**

```
    IID NAME    TEXT
0   10  One     AA,AB
1   11  Two     AB,AC,ABC,A,C
2   12  Three   AB,AA
3   13  Four    AC,AD,ABC
```